# 'Post receive hooks for binding events. '?

Tags: git, gitlab

'Post receive hooks for binding events. '
can you me explain what does mean ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every GitHub repo has the option to communicate with a web server whenever the repo is pushed to. These "WebHooks" can be used to update an external issue tracker, trigger CI builds, update a backup mirror, or even deploy to your production server.

You can read about [this topic](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) on github.